# Can someone explain me how the cartesian product works in relational algebra

Tags: cartesian-product, relational-algebra

[here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Selection_and_cross_product) it says

Selection and cross product

Cross product is the costliest operator to evaluate. If the input relations have N and M rows, the result will contain NM rows. Therefore it is very important to do our best to decrease the size of both operands before applying the cross product operator.

suppose that we have 2 relations

first relation is called Student and has 3 attributes, thus

```
    student
  |a |b   |c |
  ------------
  |__|___|___|
  |__|___|___|
  |__|___|___|
```

second relation is university and again with 3 attributes

```
   university
  |e |f   |g |
  ------------
  |__|___|___|
  |__|___|___|
  |__|___|___|
```

we have 3 rows for each relation, so after applying the cross product operation we will get a relation which has 3*3 = 9 rows

now, I don't understand, why 9 and not 3?

won't the final relation be

```
 final relation
 |a |b   |c |d |e   |f |g |
 --------------------------
 |__|___|___|__|____|__|__|
 |__|___|___|__|____|__|__|
 |__|___|___|__|____|__|__|
```

doesn't this have 3 rows again?

Thanks

Comment: This belongs on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Perception - It doesn't. relational algebra <> algebra.

Comment: @MartinSmith - thats like saying differential calculus isn't calculus.

Comment: @Perception - There are 56 relational algebra questions on SO. Can't see any on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't think that relational algebra is unique enough to the programming profession to have its questions on SO. Just going by the faq. And there are currently 755 algebra questions on math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Perception - You may be right. I'm not in a position to judge its on topicness for math.stackexchange.com to be honest.

Comment: Suggestion: get yourself a relational DBMS (e.g. [Rel](http://dbappbuilder.sourceforge.net/Rel.php)) and try it out ;)

Comment: Relational algebra operators are specifically designed to be executable with reasonable complexity & expressions calling them are functional programs & such operators & programs are used to reason about & express queries in other programming languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the rows in Student are row1, row2 and row3, and the rows in University are row4, row5 and row6, then the cartesian product will contain

row1row4, row1row5, row1row6, row2row4, row2row5, row2row6, row3row4, row3row5, row3row6

Each possible combination of rows.  That's how it is defined.  Nothing more to it.

Except for your remark "Therefore it is very important to do our best to decrease the size of both operands before applying the cross product operator.".  It is important to realise that there do exist optimizers which are able to "rewrite" certain algebra operations.  It is certainly not the case that the onus is always on the query writer to determine the "most appropriate way of combining restrictions with other operations".  In fact, "moving restrictions to the inside as far as possible" is one of the things industrial optimizers are actually very good at.

Answer (score 2):

Just imagine that you have two tables one with the students and one with the universities, when you do a Cartesian query against a relational database you will get a row for every student which in turn is joined to every university.

```
Select *
   From students, 
        universities;
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM students CROSS JOIN universities
```

I know this has little to do with algebra but since your on stackoverflow :D

Answer (score 0):

There is no common attribute to link between student and university so each row in student is matched to each row in university, 3 * 3 = 9

Answer (score 0):

|a|e|
|a|f|
|a|g|
|b|e|
|b|f|
|b|g|
|c|e|
|c|f|
|c|g|

Therefore 9